# Сбор статистики с сайта через apache или nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, статистика

Есть сайт на wordpress и крутится все это на nginx и apache. На под-доменах стоит медиа контент. Вопрос в том как организовать сбор статистики прослушивания и просмотров (обращений по url с основного сайта)? Можно ли это сделать силами апача и nginx или надо все таки запилить код с базой?
P.S. Все на ЦентОси.

Comment: вас интересуют только *факты обращения* к нужным адресам или что-то большее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[awstats](http://www.awstats.org/) Прекрасно справится с вашей задачей, он как раз парсит логи вебсервера и генерирует из них html странички для отображения статистики

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.